# Fixing CSS on login page of my site

Tags: css

I have a problem on my site's login page in IE7 browser. One of the buttons on that page http://j-in.org.ua:9000 is cut off, in IE browser

Here's the screenshot: http://img.skitch.com/20090629-nxnr2pwcs529peqxsttt96fmtk.jpg
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: It would help both you and anyone willing to help you, if you extracted the minimal example - i.e. the shortest HTML page + shortest CSS with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it to `display: block`.

```
#login #reg a { display: block; }
```